# Shall I request author premision to modify r function

Tags: r

I am working on project and would like to use some function from R package. However, for my project requirements, I must modify these functions. Then used them for my project purpose only. Of course I would like to publish my work. The modification is on these functions only and I will use the new function in my project. So I will not change the package. So my question, shall I request the author permission for these modifications? I tried to modify these function because they are so closed to what I am doing. So, I just need to modify them. I am not plan to write a package.

Comment: Is the package available on CRAN? What is the package licence?

Comment: @ColinFAY yes it is on CRAN and the license is 
"License: GPL (>= 2)"

Comment: @ColinFAY I will not change the package. I will only use the new modified functions. That is, take the needed function and modify them and used them. that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if the pkg is on CRAN and if the [Licence is GPL (>=2)](https://www.r-project.org/Licenses/LGPL-2), your are allowed to copy and modify the content as long as the modified content is still in GPL and that you state that you modified the content. So you don't need to ask for the permission of the pkg creator.

A good practice would be to create your own package, calling it 'pkgextra' (where pkg is the name of the package) and stating in the DESCRIPTION that the package is built on top of another package e.g [tidystringdist](https://github.com/ColinFay/tidystringdist) which is built on top of stringdist or [ggExtra](https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra) which is built on top of ggpot. Also, as R packages have a Dependencies component, you're clearly stating in the DESCRIPTION that you built your package depending on other packages.

To wrap up, no, you don't need the permission from the package author for as long as you distribute the created work with the same licence and that you state that you depend on this package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not want to write a package. just few functions for my project only.